# How to create a select element from a List<Object[]>?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

There is a DAO method returning a List :

```
@Transactional
public List<Object[]> list() {

    String sql = "select pnd_code, to_char(pnd_intitule) l from pnd order by l"; // pnd_intitule is a CLOB column

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) query.list();

    return list;

}
```

In my JSP I want to create a select element from it ; here is what I have tried ( but it crashed at runtime ) :

```
<select id="pnd" style="width:500px;">
    <option value=""> -- S&eacute;lectionner -- </option>
    <c:forEach items="${pnds}" var="pnd">
        <option value="${pnd.pnd_code}">${pnd.l}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

So how to create the select element in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and create a custom class that encapsulates your data.

```
class MyCustomClass{ // change name
    private final String lecturer;
    private final String code:
    // initialize fields in constructor
    // add getters
}
```

DAO class:

```
public List<MyCustomClass> list() {

    String sql = "select pnd_code, to_char(pnd_intitule) l from pnd order by l"; // pnd_intitule is a CLOB column

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    return ((List<Object[]>) query.list())
         .stream()
         .map(oo -> new MyCustomClass(oo[0].toString(), oo[1].toString()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Old-school Java 7 version:

```
public List<MyCustomClass> listWithoutLambdasAndStreams() {

    String sql = "select pnd_code, to_char(pnd_intitule) l from pnd order by l"; // pnd_intitule is a CLOB column

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
    List<MyCustomClass> youShouldReallyLearnAboutLambdasAndStreams =
        new  ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for(Object[] oo: list){
        youShouldReallyLearnAboutLambdasAndStreams.add(
            new MyCustomClass(oo[0].toString(), oo[1].toString()));
    };
    return youShouldReallyLearnAboutLambdasAndStreams;
}
```

JSP:

```
<select id="pnd" style="width:500px;">
    <option value=""> -- S&eacute;lectionner -- </option>
    <c:forEach items="${pnds}" var="pnd">
        <option value="${pnd.code}">${pnd.lecturer}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: there are errors : Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above , even if I set the project jre system library to 1.8

Comment: @pheromix then either switch to source level 1.8 or refactor my code to not use lambdas

Comment: can you please refactor it because I am not aware about lambda expressions.

Comment: @pheromix done, but do yourself a favor and learn Java 8 lambdas and streams. Once you've understood it, life gets a lot easier! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html